# Weird - 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

everyone
I use codership to connect bitbucket and AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have setup the user&group on elastic beanstalk and its policy according to codeship document.  S3 bucket also has been setup.

if I submit a index.php like welcome page. the AWS elastic beanstalk can display the page, but after i commit and push the real project, The AWS server display a 403 Forbidden error.  And I pretty sure the source code of the project is corrected(have been tested on local computer.)  The codeship display successful deploy message.

that's so weird, Can someone please help me deal with this problem

Thanks

Comment: Can you try checking logs at all? Is beanstalk serving the application?

Comment: i just checked that and here's "[Tue Apr 05 05:36:48.103966 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 17601] [client 172.31.17.177:34160] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=us-west-2
[Tue Apr 05 05:36:48.104195 2016] [pagespeed:error] [pid 17601] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @17601] Failed to make directory /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/v2: Permission denied"    the logs is too long so i just copy s

Comment: I recommend you signup for AWS support and speak with them.